# Checking out branch created at home on work computer doesn't pull latest changes

Tags: git, github

I decided to get some work done at home yesterday on my personal computer.

Both my work and home computers have clones of repo `work` and are using fork and pull so `git remote --v` shows:

```
origin  git@github.com:username/work.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:username/work.git (push)
upstream    git@github.com:companyname/work.git (fetch)
upstream    git@github.com:companyname/work.git (push)
```

I created a branch at home with:

```
git checkout master                       # start from scratch
git pull --all; git pull upstream master; # alias I use to start fresh
git checkout -b new_branch                # new feature branch to do work on
```

I finished my work and used `git push --set-upstream origin new_branch` which fixes the warning I receive whenever I use `git push` for the first time after using `git checkout -b` in my situation.

I then initiated a pull request on github from `username:new_branch` to `companyname:master` to merge my work back into the remote master branch.

I went to work the next day and fired up my work computer and changes were requested to my PR so naturally I did:

```
git checkout new_branch
```

Which says `new branch created to track changes`. Now that can't be right because the branch already exists. I made it just last night. Do a lot of googling and then do the following:

```
git branch -a              # shows my branch as remotes/origin/new_branch
git branch -d new_branch   # remove the local branch with no changes in it
git checkout -b new_branch origin/new_branch # correctly check out remote branch and supposedly the changes
```

But here's where it's confusing. `git log` shows the commit I made last night as the most recent commit but the code I'm looking at doesn't reflect the changes of the latest commit in the log.

I've also tried:

```
git checkout origin/new_branch   # shows detached HEAD but no changes
git checkout sha1ofcommit        # shows detached HEAD but no changes
git checkout -b new_branch remotes/origin/new_branch # shows no changes
```

Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which says new branch created to track changes. Now that can't be right because the branch already exists. I made it just last night.

No, it was right.  Branches are repo-specific.  You created it on your home computer's repo, then pushed it to `origin`; but your work computer didn't have it yet.  Then you fetched at work, so you got a remote tracking ref (`origin/new_branch`) that tells you where `new_branch` is at on `origin`; this *still* is not a branch in your work computer's local repo.

When you said `git checkout new_branch`, git saw that there was a remote tracking ref for a `new_branch` in exactly one remote, so *then* it created the corresponding local branch, pointing to the same commit as on `origin`.  Your code would have been at the correct state at this point.

But then you deleted the local branch and re-created it with `-b`; in this case `git` assumes you mean to create a new local branch independent of anything that might exist on any remote.  So if you weren't at the `origin/new_branch` commit when you did this, then what you did is move `new_branch` to the wrong commit.

There are several ways to fix this.  Since you'll probably want tracking properly set up, I'd say the easiest is

```
git branch -D new_branch
git branch new_branch
```

which will again tell you it's creating a new branch, but then look at the state of your code.  If it's not right, something else is going on beyond what you've conveyed so far.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mark. I ended up deleting the repo and re-cloning on my work computer and the branch checked out as expected and contained my changes from the origin/branch. I've been heavily reworking the repo so I think it was related to having local files that were undeleted or some other issue with the physical files inside the repo folder itself rather than the git commands I was performing.